# high memory consumption in basic react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was making my first react native and as much easy I though it would be, it is turning out to be difficult for me to understand what I could be doing wrong.

To start with, I have a very simple app which fetches data through redux

```
componentWillMount() {

    this.props.fetchCoin()
    this.props.CurrencyRate()
  }
```

and then renders this in its return part

```
 return (
     <ScrollView>
                 <Header />
                 {/* Custom Search Input */}
                 <View>
                 <TextInput
                  style={textInput}
                  placeholder="Search Coin"
                  onChangeText={(text) => this.onSearch(text)} />
                  </View>
                  <View>
                  <FlatList
                   data={this.state.searchCoin ? displaySearchCrypto : this.props.cryptoLoaded}
                   renderItem={({ item }) => (
                   <CoinCard
                      key={item["long"]}
                      coinShortName = {item["short"]}
                      coinName = {item["long"]}
                      coinPrice = {item["price"].toFixed(2)}
                      marketCap = {(item["mktcap"]/1000000000).toFixed(4)}
                      percentChange = {item["perc"].toFixed(2)}
                      vwapData={item["vwapData"].toFixed(2)}
                      coinImage={"https://coincap.io/images/coins/" + item["long"] + ".png"}
                      />
                  )}
          />
          </View>
               </ScrollView>
           )
      }
    }
```

> I am seeing my ram consumption to be greater than 500 MB even after
>   the app have fetched data and UI thread sticked to 60 (fps) where i
>   think nothing in UI is happening

Instead of sharing all my code: You can find most of the stuff at github
The above snippet code is shared from here: https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/container/cryptoContainer.js

The CoinCard Component in the above code can be seen here: https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/components/CoinCard.js

And Action for the same is here: https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/actions/cryptoAction.js

**[Question:]** Can someone please help me find out what am I doing wrong and how could I fix it? [This repository](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/actions/cryptoAction.js) should work on your simulator without throwing an error if in case someone wants [try it out](https://github.com/irohitb/Crypto/blob/master/src/actions/cryptoAction.js).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlatList` with `Image` has an open issue on Android: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413. There are some tips on performance here: https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips/

As a first attempt to fix, try  adding `removeClippedSubviews` to your `FlatList`, although that comes with trade offs.

I also note in the screenshot that you are getting a warning about missing keys. Fix that issue and try `keyExtractor` and see if that improves things.

Alternatively, use something other than `FlatList`, e.g. `ScrollView`. You will lose some of the features of the `FlatList` but if you get acceptable memory usage and performance, it may be worth it.

Comment: Can you help me with diagnosing if there is a memory leak? Like do you know any article which can me with the same?

Comment: See this linked [project](https://github.com/stoffern/react-native-optimized-flatlist) in the GitHub issue. It claims to have solved at least some of the issue. The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance) have some good tips also.